# Start index in jquery for carousel effect not working properly

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myshec274008d:611/Style Library/js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script> 
   <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function ($) {

                    $('#jcarouselBlogs').jcarousel({ 
                        scroll: 4,
                        start: '<%=(indexElement)%>'

                    });
}
```

index element value is coming from code behind of c# page load.
When the page loads the start index is the first item i see. but when i scroll some data is lost. On the other hand if i hard code the value of start for eg:- 11 everything works fine. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `'<%=(indexElement)%>'` to `<%=indexElement%>`

Also, there's a good example here: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_start.html

Check the console logs as well to see if there are any errors, if so please report them here.

Comment: removing the brackets didn't work. i checked the logs there are no errors. only problem i m facing is that i m losing few items.

Comment: the link you gave is the exact requirement i have only with condition that start index should be dynamic.

Comment: Did you remove the `'`s as well?

Comment: great it worked. how did u do that? i mean i know whats wrong but why?

Comment: Probably because it was looking for an integer and you were passing a string (wrapping it in `'`s)

Answer (score 0):

try use:

```
                    $('#jcarouselBlogs').jcarousel({ 
                        scroll: 4,
                        start: <%=(indexElement ?? 0)%>
                    });
```

Comment: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'
This the error i got. indexelement is of type int